# pfSense and Disabling SURICATA UDPv4 invalid checksum

Tags: pfsense, snort

We have a pfSense router running with packet inspection. Our logs are filling up with these requests:

```
SURICATA UDPv4 invalid checksum
```

Research shows that we should do the following:

```
Disable the stream-events.rules via SID Mgmt. (Yeah, I mean the whole category. Zillions of FPs.)
```

However, I can't find that stream-events.rules under the categories list.

We are running pfSense with suricata using snort related rules.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to this site, you can create a `disablesid.conf` file that looks somewhat like this (there's extra in this, use what you need)

https://forum.pfsense.org/index.php?topic=95881.0

```
# Messes up with DNS resolution on LAN
1:2200073 # SURICATA IPv4 invalid checksum
# Bittorrent noise, DNS
1:2200075 # SURICATA UDPv4 invalid checksum
1:2200078 # SURICATA UDPv6 invalid checksum
# Lots of useless noise
1:2200076 # SURICATA ICMPv4 invalid checksum
1:2200079 # SURICATA ICMPv6 invalid checksum
```

Then set it as the **Disable SID File** for the interface you are interested in.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post but I had an issue finding answers that got straight to the point. With the recent update, you can edit Suricata rules from the GUI.

Services tab>Suricata>Interfaces>edit via pencil icon in interface list under "actions" column>lan (or wan) rules.

Choose the category of the alert that you wish to change. In this case it would be "decoder-events.rules". Just refer back to your interface alerts if needed. I use ctrl+F to look for the specific SID I want to change on this page and just hit the icon under the "state" column. Make sure you hit apply. Hope this helps someone!